# Android: implement time based reminders

Tags: android

In my application I need to have notifications at specific times in weekdays as reminders to the user. I also need to have them run even in the background. What's the best way to proceed to handle both background process and reminders in the application?

My data is stored as simple text in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `AlarmManager` class with methods `setExact` or `setWindow`. Read more about AlarmManager [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: so i dont need to take care of background service in this approach?
and can i make a notification to the user at that alarm time?

Comment: You need to use a broadcast receiver which will handle the alarm. What you do from there is up to you.